# Undefined reference to in Constructor with QNetworkAccessManager derived class

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qtnetwork, moc

I am trying to read a html page using the following code which uses Qt libraries

```
 #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
    #include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
    #include <QtCore/QString>
    #include <iostream>

    class SillyRequest : public QNetworkAccessManager

{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        SillyRequest();
        QString getData();
    public slots:
        void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *);
    private:
       QString collectedData;
};
QString SillyRequest :: getData()
{
    return collectedData;
}
SillyRequest :: SillyRequest()
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void SillyRequest :: replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) 
{
    collectedData = reply->readAll();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    SillyRequest *network = new SillyRequest;

    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com"));

    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");

    QNetworkReply *reply = network->get(request);

    std :: cout << network->getData().toStdString() << std :: endl;

    return app.exec();

}
```

I get the following error when I compile. Am not sure what I am not doing in the right way.

```
testing.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `vtable for SillyRequest'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:192: recipe for target 'network' failed
make: *** [network] Error 1
```

I have inherited from QNetworkAccessManager so as to implement the 'replyFinished' slot. Signal 'finished' is already part of the 'QNetworkAccessManager'.

Comment: does `SillyRequest` have any virtual methods?

Comment: Inside the constructor, try `connect (..., SLOT(SillyRequest::replyFinished(QNetworkReply*))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many issues with your short code, but I will focus below on the most central part of those.

## Include the moc file

The general practice is this:

```
void SillyRequest :: replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) 
{
    collectedData = reply->readAll();
}

#include "main.moc" // This is the addition

int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

The problem is that your class is not in separate header and source files and so qmake and hence moc are in no position to be aware of this.

As a side note, you could also inline all the methods in this special case.

## Separate header and source

If you do not want to explicitly include the moc (meta object compiler) file generated on the fly, you would need to establish a separate header (and preferably source) for your own class and then you can include the header in your main.cpp file. You would then do this in the beginning of the `main.cpp`:

```
#include "sillyrequest.h"
```

and naturally, you would extend the qmake project file as follows:

```
HEADERS = sillyrequest.h
SOURCES = sillyrequest.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: Why do you suggest the use of inline methods in this particular case?

Comment: @Aslaville: 1) These are inlineable short methods, so it is more explicit to the compiler to optimize it out potentially making it slightly faster. 2) Code would become shorter, too.

Comment: @Aslaville: since you have 13 questions with no answer accepted, [please read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you had not done it so; not necessarily saying to accept this answer, but looking at your record, it seems you have got several good answers which oughta solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QtCreator, try adding this line at bottom of testing.cpp

```
#include "testing.moc"
```